# Pegar html de input preenchido com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Preciso pegar html do input como texto, assim:

```
var exemplo = 'input type="text" name="input" id="input"';
```

Porém, preciso pegar o input preenchido, ficaria assim:

```
var exemplo = 'input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="VALOR QUE ESCREVI"';
```

É possível fazer?

Comment: `$('#input').val()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```js
function tag(){
   var exemplo = $("#input")  // pega o elemento
   .attr("value", function(){ return this.value }) // insere o atributo com o valor atual inserido
   .prop('outerHTML'); // retorna o HTML em forma de string

   console.log(exemplo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Escreva alguma coisa no campo:
<br>
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
<br>
<button onclick="tag()">Pegar string</button>
```

Se quiser sem os delimitadores `<` e `>`, use `exemplo.replace(/<|>/g, "");`:

```js
function tag(){
   var exemplo = $("#input")  // pega o elemento.
   .attr("value", function(){ return this.value }) // insere o atributo com o valor atual inserido
   .prop("outerHTML"); // retorna o HTML em forma de string

   exemplo = exemplo.replace(/<|>/g, "");

   console.log(exemplo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Escreva alguma coisa no campo:
<br>
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
<br>
<button onclick="tag()">Pegar string</button>
```

Comment: top mano, valeu! E se eu quiser um form todo preenchido dessa forma, vou precisar fazer input por input?

Comment: Aí eu teria que ver como fazer.